# Reading a multiline file with "&" as separator

Tags: python, string, input

I have a file which contains the following content:

```
This is the first line.
&
This is the second line
but without separator.
&
This is the third line.
...
```

Each line terminates with a `\n`. I want to convert this file input into the following list:
`['This is the first line.', 'This is the second line but without separator.', 'This is the third line.', ...]`

My actual code looks like:

```
file = open("/path/to/file", "r")
list = [line.rstrip() for line in file if not line.rstrip() is "&"]
```

The problem is that the multi line section gets separated in the list but I want it togehter with or without a `\n` in it.

I hope someone can give me a hint. Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `if not line.rstrip() is "*"` to do? Why do you think it'll remove lines that are `"&"` and join lines not separated by one?

Comment: `[i.replace("\n","") for i in line.split("&")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just split the whole file by `&` and remove whitespace (assuming that they should just be separated by `&`)

```py
l = [s.strip().replace('\n', ' ') for s in file.read().split('&')]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good solution for my problem. I just added a `\n` at `.split('&\n)` so a `&` can be in the sentence.

Comment: Or just replace _before_ splitting by `&`. `l = file.read().replace('\n', ' ').split('&')` eliminates the need for any iteration.

Answer (score 1):

How about read all the lines and join them as a single string, then use String.split("&")

```py
with open("test.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read()

print(lines.split("&"))
# to remove the \n
print(lines.replace("\n", "").split("&"))
```

Comment: Also replace all `\n` with one space from `lines`.

Comment: The answer above seems to solve the problem. I will update the code as well here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.  You already know how to read the file, here is how you might parse the contents.

```
file_contents = """This is the first line.
&
This is the second line
but without separator.
&
This is the third line."""

all_lines = []
for l in file_contents.split('&'):
    all_lines.append(" ".join(l.split('\n')).rstrip())

print(all_lines)
```

Prints:

```
['This is the first line.', ' This is the second line but without separator.', ' This is the third line.']
```